# Discrete Set of $\mathbb{R}^2$ Enclosed by Proper Open Connected Set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $S\subseteq T$ be a closed discrete subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (with its usual topology) where $T$ is an open connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I'm asking for any hint on how to show that there exists a proper open connected subset of $T$ that contains $S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $S$ is non-empty. Take some point $s \in S$. Since $S$ is discrete, there is some open ball $B(s,r) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $B(s,r) \cap S = \{s\}$. In fact, we can choose $r$ small enough such that $B(s,r) \subset T$ since $T$ is open and $T$ contains $s$. Then choose some point of $B(s,r)$ different from $s$, call it $s'$. The set $T \setminus \{s'\}$ is a connected proper open subset of $T$ containing $S$.